# should I have to npm install for every react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules

I am learning react and I have 30 projects with setup/final version..and each install is taking 150 - 200 mb nothing special about dependency..Is there a way sym link the node_modules to these. rather taking up 30x150mb :(

I tried setting up NODE_PATH and PATH to the NODE_PATH bin directory for the react-script to a common place but doesn't work.

Comment: Are you working on the 30 projects all at once? If memory usage is an issue, delete `node_modules` from the unused project, and if these projects are ever worked on again, install the project again.

Comment: everytime you want to run a project install and again delete and again install..something is not right

Comment: https://pnpm.io/ is an option that does symlinking/hard linking automagically for you.

Comment: thanks @AKX. should be good for now...will go with pnpm for test projects and for real project with npm as I don't know about the stablilty for pnpm for real development projects.

Comment: pnpm should be stable enough (if not even more stable) so I guess it's a good replacement for npm! Though it might install multiple versions of React if the different projects depends on different versions (in their `package.json` file).

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't. Since all of your projects might be different based on what they are, you simply can't use the same react library everywhere by installing it once. You will have to install it separately for each project.

Comment: As I said these are pretty basic projects  nothing fancy dependencies..It should go with basic react dependency

Comment: @coool Even though they are pretty basic projects and understand you very well. But React is not particularly a library that can be reused. E.g. if you have ever used `nodemon` which helps us restart the node server. It is a reusable library which means that the work it does is the same for all projects. That's why you would install it globally. You can't do the same with react.

Comment: I wouldn't even install `nodemon` globally in a project (maybe as a CLI tool for me as a user, but not as a project dependency).

Comment: @EmileBergeron You have it wrong here. If you install a library globally then it does not become a dependency on your project

Comment: @CodeFingers that's exactly the issue, I want my colleagues to be able to run a project without them having to figure out what other tools they need to install and end up with a different version anyway.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Can't seem to find an answer to it there then. I'm sorry

Comment: The solution in the case I described would be to install `nodemon` as a project dependency, hence my initial comment.